# List in sheet doesn't update list in form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm a beginner at this so apologies.  I'm trying to have a sheet with data in column A be the options in a specific list in a form. Ultimately I would like many columns of data be the reference of specific lists.  The form doesn't need to sync with the list. I'd prefer to do that by running script in sheet.

This is how far I am but it's only pulling cell A1.
Right now the form is simple and only has one drop down question.

Many thanks for any help.

```
var FORM_ID = '1Edo3yPmfPLQXPRff6z8oDsYW0Hp-Mm5SYLISPnyTXfo';
var LIST_SHEET_NAME = 'List';
var range = 'A:A';
var ITEM_ID = '983918997';

function updateListInForm() {
    var values_ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName(LIST_SHEET_NAME)
        .getRange(range)
        .getValues();

    values_[0][0] = values_[0][0].toString();

    for (var i = 1; i < values_.lenght; i++) {
        values_[0].push(values_[i][0].toString())
    }
    var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
    var list = form.getItemById(ITEM_ID);
    list.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values_[0]);

    function getitemsofform() {
        var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_ID);
        var items = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST);
        for (var i in items) {
            Logger.log('id: ' + items[i].getId() + ' title: ' + items[i].getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing. Can anyone point me to a program or app that teaches google script?  I would like to start from scratch. ie. this is what var means, this is how to write a simple function

Comment: I believe the free [FormRange add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/formranger/faepkjkcpnnghgdhiobglpppbfdnaehc?hl=en) may already do what you want.  As for learning from scratch, you may want to look into learning JavaScript, which Google Apps Script (GAS) is built on and then add in the GAS portion. That said, I started in GAS and used a lot of Google searches to get me going.  I never found an actual place to learn starting from the basics.

Comment: Hi @Scott-Curley welcome to stack overflow :) - sorry I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but I was invited to review your "beginner post" and have cleaned up the tabs in your code sample. It should make it easier to read for the person who DOES know the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Karl. I was trying to stay away form ranger or any other add on.

Comment: Here is a tutorial:  [Link - Learn JavaScript] (https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)